# Match each dictionary value with csv column entry and apply dictionary key to new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, apply

I want to match dictionary values with an entry in a csv dataframe column and put the corresponding dictionary key in a new column.

I have a csv dataframe with a Link and six columns with numbers. I have a dictionary with Sites and many Links.

```
import pandas as pd
 
# reproducible data
data = {'Link': ['A1', 'B2', 'X7', '8G'],
        'Town1': [0.124052256, 0.939612252, 0.861338299, 0.981016558],
       'Town2': [0.605572804, 0.561737172, 0.479567258, 0.476371433],
       'Town3': [0.41687511, 0.321543551, 0.1243927, 0.097894068],
       'Town4': [0.068305033, 0.280721459, 0.600126058,0.93097328]}
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
# Print the output.
df

#Dictionary
d = {'Sample1': '[A1, 6H, 8J, A3, 4L]', 'Sample2': '[X7, 8G, 4R]', 'Sample3': '[B2, V6, 8U]' }
```

###What I want is to find where the dictionary value and the entry in the 'Link' column match and make a new column on the same csv file with the dictionary key.

This is what I tried and it returned None in the new column

```
def get_key(node):
    for node in df['Link']:
        if node in d.values():
            return d.keys()


df['Parent'] = df['Link'].apply(lambda x: get_key(x))
df
```

Output like this:[image]

Last thing I want is to .groupby.sum() the df['Parent'] column and make a final pivot table of the Samples and the sum in each of the 'Town' columns.

Final table example:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of : input -> expected output ?

Comment: Just curious, what do values like .1 and .6 for the A1 link mean w.r.t. the first two towns, in the real world? It would help to motivate the problem, encourage an intuitive understanding.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "find where the dictionary value and the entry ... match" -- define "match", please. Also, help us to understand what "make a new column" means. Named "parent"? what would the value(s) mean? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Including an example desired result dataframe would go a long way toward resolving such ambiguities.

Comment: It seems you have a mistake in your example. There is no '8G' in 'Sample1'. There is '8J', though.

Comment: Can there be a case when there are more than one match in values, and more than one key is involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def matcher(find_this_value):
    your_dict = {'Sample1': ['A1', '6H', '8J', 'A3', '4L'], 'Sample2': ['X7', '8G', '4R'], 'Sample3': ['B2', 'V6', '8U']}
    for key, values in your_dict.items():
       for value in values:
          if find_this_value in value:
             return key

df['dict_key'] = df['Link'].apply(matcher)
```

Comment: Perfect, then df.groupby('dict_key').sum() gives the final table. Thanks !